# Cannot uninstall numpy on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, ubuntu, pip

It seems my pip is broken:

```
ubuntu@ip-x:~$ pip3 uninstall numpy
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.5
ERROR: Cannot uninstall numpy 1.19.5, RECORD file not found. You might be able to recover from this via: 'pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.19.5'.
```

```
ubuntu@ip-x:~$ python3 -m pip uninstall numpy
Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.5
ERROR: Cannot uninstall numpy 1.19.5, RECORD file not found. You might be able to recover from this via: 'pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.19.5'.
```

```
ubuntu@ip-x:~$ sudo apt remove python3-numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python3-numpy' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 71 not upgraded.
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-42:~$
```

Why I cannot uninstall numpy?

EDIT: not sure if it could be related but I have OpenVINO installed

EDIT2: I tried the suggested solution, but it does not work:

```
ubuntu@ip-x:~$ pip3 install --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.19.5
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting numpy==1.19.5
  Downloading numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 14.8 MB 6.3 MB/s            
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.5
ERROR: Cannot uninstall numpy 1.19.5, RECORD file not found. You might be able to recover from this via: 'pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.19.5'.
```

EDIT3: I am trying to install because I am have some issues with numpy. I think there are different versions, compare:

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.5
ERROR: Cannot uninstall numpy 1.19.5, RECORD file not found. You might be able to recover from this via: 'pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.19.5'.
```

with

```
ubuntu@x:~$ python3 -c "import numpy;print(numpy.__version__);print(numpy.__file__)";
1.18.5
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py
```

EDIT4: I can't use `numba`:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting numba
  Downloading numba-0.53.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.4 MB 7.9 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from numba) (58.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from numba) (1.19.5)
Collecting llvmlite<0.37,>=0.36.0rc1
  Downloading llvmlite-0.36.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (25.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 25.3 MB 128.3 MB/s            
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy-1.19.5.dist-info/METADATA'
```

Comment: Have you tried running the suggested command?

Comment: incidentally, *why* are you trying to uninstall numpy?

Comment: Suggested solution gives me the same error.

Comment: See above for the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I fixed with:

```
pip3 install --user --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.19.5
```

At least that got numpy and numba working.

Answer (score 1):

Because your numpy installation is either broken, or was not handled by pip:

```
ERROR: Cannot uninstall numpy 1.19.5, RECORD file not found.
```

Either take the brute force solution provided, or track down where the numpy files actually came from---have a look in your PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate solution is removing numpy directrly

```
rm -rf ~/.local/lib/python/site-packages/numpy
pip install numpy
```

but first you should check which python do you user and find yout site-packages path

Comment: Directory ` ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy` does not exist.

Comment: try to detect your python version

Comment: user command "which python"

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3` but `cd ~/.local/lib/python3` does not exist. Only `~/.local/lib/python3.6` exists.

Comment: so try to use your path - rm -rf ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy

Answer (score -1):

1. You can find installed packages with this command
   `pip freeze`
2. I recommend you to use [virtual enviroment](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/introduction-to-virtual-environments-and-dependency-managers/#:%7E:text=A%20virtual%20environment%20is%20an,management%20of%20a%20project%27s%20dependencies.)

Comment: thx i saw apt usage in question and thought that in can be executable package "numpy"

Comment: Yes, `which numpy` returns `numpy not found`.

Comment: i changed command